# How do I do use wave function collapse on 3d meshes in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, procedural-generation

Im quite new to programming and I've been really interested in WFC recently and I also love procedural terrain generation so combining the 2 seemed like a good idea but I cant figure out how to convert the 2d WFC algorithm I have into 3d :( any help would be appreciated. Or if anyone has a good tutorial for a 3d version that would be good too thanks :)

heres the code for the 2d version of the alogrithm :

Cell:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Cell : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool collapsed;
    public Tile[] tileOptions;

    public void CreateCell(bool collapseState, Tile[] tiles)
    {
        collapsed = collapseState;
        tileOptions = tiles;
    }

    public void RecreateCell(Tile[] tiles)
    {
        tileOptions = tiles;
    }
}
```

Tile:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Tile : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Tile[] upNeighbours;
    public Tile[] rightNeighbours;
    public Tile[] downNeighbours;
    public Tile[] leftNeighbours;
}
```

WaveFunction:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Unity.Mathematics;
using UnityEngine;

public class WaveFunction : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int dimensions;
    public Tile[] tileObjects;
    public List<Cell> gridComponents;
    public Cell cellObj;

    int iterations = 0;

    void Awake()
    {
        gridComponents = new List<Cell>();
        InitializeGrid();
    }

    void InitializeGrid()
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < dimensions; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < dimensions; x++)
            {
                Cell newCell = Instantiate(cellObj, new Vector2(x, y), Quaternion.identity);
                newCell.CreateCell(false, tileObjects);
                gridComponents.Add(newCell);
            }
        }

        StartCoroutine(CheckEntropy());
    }


    IEnumerator CheckEntropy()
    {
        List<Cell> tempGrid = new List<Cell>(gridComponents);

        tempGrid.RemoveAll(c => c.collapsed);

        tempGrid.Sort((a, b) => { return a.tileOptions.Length - b.tileOptions.Length; });

        int arrLength = tempGrid[0].tileOptions.Length;
        int stopIndex = default;

        for (int i = 1; i < tempGrid.Count; i++)
        {
            if (tempGrid[i].tileOptions.Length > arrLength)
            {
                stopIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (stopIndex > 0)
        {
            tempGrid.RemoveRange(stopIndex, tempGrid.Count - stopIndex);
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.01f);

        CollapseCell(tempGrid);
    }

    void CollapseCell(List<Cell> tempGrid)
    {
        int randIndex = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, tempGrid.Count);

        Cell cellToCollapse = tempGrid[randIndex];

        cellToCollapse.collapsed = true;
        Tile selectedTile = cellToCollapse.tileOptions[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, cellToCollapse.tileOptions.Length)];
        cellToCollapse.tileOptions = new Tile[] { selectedTile };

        Tile foundTile = cellToCollapse.tileOptions[0];
        Instantiate(foundTile, cellToCollapse.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

        UpdateGeneration();
    }

    void UpdateGeneration()
    {
        List<Cell> newGenerationCell = new List<Cell>(gridComponents);

        for (int y = 0; y < dimensions; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < dimensions; x++)
            {
                var index = x + y * dimensions;
                if (gridComponents[index].collapsed)
                {
                    Debug.Log("called");
                    newGenerationCell[index] = gridComponents[index];
                }
                else
                {
                    List<Tile> options = new List<Tile>();
                    foreach (Tile t in tileObjects)
                    {
                        options.Add(t);
                    }

                    //update above
                    if (y > 0)
                    {
                        Cell up = gridComponents[x + (y - 1) * dimensions];
                        List<Tile> validOptions = new List<Tile>();

                        foreach (Tile possibleOptions in up.tileOptions)
                        {
                            var valOption = Array.FindIndex(tileObjects, obj => obj == possibleOptions);
                            var valid = tileObjects[valOption].upNeighbours;

                            validOptions = validOptions.Concat(valid).ToList();
                        }

                        CheckValidity(options, validOptions);
                    }

                    //update right
                    if (x < dimensions - 1)
                    {
                        Cell right = gridComponents[x + 1 + y * dimensions];
                        List<Tile> validOptions = new List<Tile>();

                        foreach (Tile possibleOptions in right.tileOptions)
                        {
                            var valOption = Array.FindIndex(tileObjects, obj => obj == possibleOptions);
                            var valid = tileObjects[valOption].leftNeighbours;

                            validOptions = validOptions.Concat(valid).ToList();
                        }

                        CheckValidity(options, validOptions);
                    }

                    //look down
                    if (y < dimensions - 1)
                    {
                        Cell down = gridComponents[x + (y + 1) * dimensions];
                        List<Tile> validOptions = new List<Tile>();

                        foreach (Tile possibleOptions in down.tileOptions)
                        {
                            var valOption = Array.FindIndex(tileObjects, obj => obj == possibleOptions);
                            var valid = tileObjects[valOption].downNeighbours;

                            validOptions = validOptions.Concat(valid).ToList();
                        }

                        CheckValidity(options, validOptions);
                    }

                    //look left
                    if (x > 0)
                    {
                        Cell left = gridComponents[x - 1 + y * dimensions];
                        List<Tile> validOptions = new List<Tile>();

                        foreach (Tile possibleOptions in left.tileOptions)
                        {
                            var valOption = Array.FindIndex(tileObjects, obj => obj == possibleOptions);
                            var valid = tileObjects[valOption].rightNeighbours;

                            validOptions = validOptions.Concat(valid).ToList();
                        }

                        CheckValidity(options, validOptions);
                    }

                    Tile[] newTileList = new Tile[options.Count];

                    for (int i = 0; i < options.Count; i++)
                    {
                        newTileList[i] = options[i];
                    }

                    newGenerationCell[index].RecreateCell(newTileList);
                }
            }
        }

        gridComponents = newGenerationCell;
        iterations++;

        if (iterations < dimensions * dimensions)
        {
            StartCoroutine(CheckEntropy());
        }

    }

    void CheckValidity(List<Tile> optionList, List<Tile> validOption)
    {
        for (int x = optionList.Count - 1; x >= 0; x--)
        {
            var element = optionList[x];
            if (!validOption.Contains(element))
            {
                optionList.RemoveAt(x);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you edit your question so that it is more specific - at the moment you are simply saying you are having problems, but not saying what exactly is blocking your way. 3D WFC is too complex a topic for someone to just post a direct solution like that, so if you say specifically what part of it is causing you issues (eg. instantiating the cells, or specifying neighbours, having run time exceptions, etc) it would make it a lot easier for us to help you out